# How can I automate an R code in order to perform GWR prediction?

Tags: r, automation

The goal is to automate some code I have in `R`. The code is to perform `GWR`. I have a `csv` file which contains 33 columns:

1. the first two columns contains the x and y coordinates
2. the second column is the dependent variable
3. the rest thirty columns are my independent variables
4. And one raster which I  am using to make predictions at a finer spatial scale.

What I would like my code to do is to change in every iteration the independent variable (see the code below).

When I run the code (code 1, the automated way) I am receiving this error: `Error in validObject(.Object): invalid class “SpatialPointsDataFrame” object: number of rows in data.frame and SpatialPoints don't match`

When I run the code manually, I receive no error (see the code 2)

**CODE 1, AUTOMATED WAY**

```
library(GWmodel)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(sp)

wd = "path/"
provoliko = "ESRI:54009"

pop = raster(paste(wd, "pop.tif", sep = ""))
# raster used for prediction
regpoints <- as(pop, "SpatialPoints")

# csv containing the dependent and independent vars
block.data = read.csv(paste0(wd, "block.data.psf.csv"))
csvlist = list(colnames(subset(block.data, select = -c(x, y, ntl))))

coordinates(block.data) <- c("x", "y")
proj4string(block.data) <- provoliko

for (i in csvlist) {
  for (j in i){
    popnum = gsub("\\D+", "", j)
    
    print(popnum)
    
    # specify a model equation
    eq1 <- ntl ~ get(j)
    
    abw = bw.gwr(eq1, 
                 data = block.data, 
                 approach = "AIC", 
                 kernel = "gaussian",
                 adaptive = TRUE, 
                 p = 2,
                 parallel.method = "omp",
                 parallel.arg = "omp")
    
    ab_gwr = gwr.basic(eq1, 
                       data = block.data, 
                       regression.points = regpoints,
                       bw = abw, 
                       kernel = "gaussian", 
                       adaptive = TRUE, 
                       p = 2, 
                       F123.test = FALSE,
                       cv = FALSE,
                       parallel.method = "omp",
                       parallel.arg = "omp")
    
    sp <- ab_gwr$SDF
    sf <- st_as_sf(sp)
    
    # intercept
    intercept = as.data.frame(sf$Intercept)
    intercept = SpatialPointsDataFrame(data = intercept, coords = regpoints)
    gridded(intercept) <- TRUE
    intercept <- raster(intercept)
    raster::crs(intercept) <- provoliko
    
    intercept = resample(intercept, pop, method = "bilinear")
    
    # slope
    slope = as.data.frame(sf$pop)
    slope = SpatialPointsDataFrame(data = slope, coords = regpoints)
    gridded(slope) <- TRUE
    slope <- raster(slope)
    raster::crs(slope) <- provoliko
    
    slope = resample(slope, pop, method = "bilinear")
    
    gwr_pred = intercept + slope * pop
    
    gwr_pred[gwr_pred <= 0] <- 0
    
    writeRaster(r,
                filename = paste("path/gwr_pred", 
                                 popnum, 
                                 ".tif", 
                                 sep=""),
                format = "GTiff",
                overwrite = T)
  }
}
```

**CODE 2, MANUAL WAY**

```
library(GWmodel)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(sp)

wd = "path/"
provoliko = "ESRI:54009"
    
pop = raster(paste0(wd, "pop.tif"))
regpoints <- as(pop, "SpatialPoints")

block.data = read.csv(paste0(wd, "block.data.psf.csv"))

coordinates(block.data) <- c("x", "y")
proj4string(block.data) <- provoliko

eq1 <- ntl ~ pop010
abw = bw.gwr(eq1, 
             data = block.data, 
             approach = "AIC", 
             kernel = "gaussian",
             adaptive = TRUE, 
             p = 2,
             parallel.method = "omp",
             parallel.arg = "omp")

ab_gwr = gwr.basic(eq1, 
                   data = block.data, 
                   regression.points = regpoints,
                   bw = abw, 
                   kernel = "gaussian", 
                   adaptive = TRUE, 
                   p = 2, 
                   F123.test = FALSE,
                   cv = FALSE,
                   parallel.method = "omp",
                   parallel.arg = "omp")

# ab_gwr

sp <- ab_gwr$SDF
sf <- st_as_sf(sp)

# intercept
intercept = as.data.frame(sf$Intercept)
intercept = SpatialPointsDataFrame(data = intercept, coords = regpoints)
gridded(intercept) <- TRUE
intercept <- raster(intercept)
raster::crs(intercept) <- provoliko

intercept = resample(intercept, pop, method = "bilinear")

# slope
slope = as.data.frame(sf$pop)
slope = SpatialPointsDataFrame(data = slope, coords = regpoints)
gridded(slope) <- TRUE
slope <- raster(slope)
raster::crs(slope) <- provoliko

slope = resample(slope, pop, method = "bilinear")

gwr_pred = intercept + slope * pop

gwr_pred[gwr_pred <= 0] <- 0

writeRaster(gwr_pred, 
            paste(wd, "gwr_pred010.tif", sep = ""), 
            overwrite = TRUE)
```

A smaller sample of the dataset (3 independent variables) can be downloaded from [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1V115zpdU2-5fXssI6iWv_F6aNu4E5qA7?usp=sharing).

Comment: Try replacing `eq1 <- ntl ~ get(j)` with `eq1 <- reformulate(j, response="ntl")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@DaveArmstrong gave the solution. The complete code is:

```
library(GWmodel)
library(raster)
library(sf)
library(sp)

wd = "path/"
provoliko = "ESRI:54009"

pop = raster(paste(wd, "pop.tif", sep = ""))
regpoints <- as(pop, "SpatialPoints")

# csv containing the dependent and independent vars
block.data = read.csv(paste0(wd, "block.data.psf.csv"))
csvlist = list(colnames(subset(block.data, select = -c(x, y, ntl))))

coordinates(block.data) <- c("x", "y")
proj4string(block.data) <- provoliko

for (i in csvlist) {
  for (j in i){
    popnum = gsub("\\D+", "", j)
    
    print(popnum)
    
    # specify a model equation
    eq1 <- reformulate(j, response="ntl")
    
    abw = bw.gwr(eq1, 
                 data = block.data, 
                 approach = "AIC", 
                 kernel = "gaussian",
                 adaptive = TRUE, 
                 p = 2,
                 parallel.method = "omp",
                 parallel.arg = "omp")
    
    ab_gwr = gwr.basic(eq1, 
                       data = block.data, 
                       regression.points = regpoints,
                       bw = abw, 
                       kernel = "gaussian", 
                       adaptive = TRUE, 
                       p = 2, 
                       F123.test = FALSE,
                       cv = FALSE,
                       parallel.method = "omp",
                       parallel.arg = "omp")
    
    sp <- ab_gwr$SDF
    sf <- st_as_sf(sp)
    
    # intercept
    intercept = as.data.frame(sf$Intercept)
    intercept = SpatialPointsDataFrame(data = intercept, coords = regpoints)
    gridded(intercept) <- TRUE
    intercept <- raster(intercept)
    raster::crs(intercept) <- provoliko
    
    intercept = resample(intercept, pop, method = "bilinear")
    
    # slope
    slope = as.data.frame(sf$pop)
    slope = SpatialPointsDataFrame(data = slope, coords = regpoints)
    gridded(slope) <- TRUE
    slope <- raster(slope)
    raster::crs(slope) <- provoliko
    
    slope = resample(slope, pop, method = "bilinear")
    
    gwr_pred = intercept + slope * pop
    
    gwr_pred[gwr_pred <= 0] <- 0
    
    writeRaster(gwr_pred,
                filename = paste("path/gwr_pred", 
                                 popnum, 
                                 ".tif", 
                                 sep=""),
                format = "GTiff",
                overwrite = T)
  }
}
```